# SQL Sever Alwayson - Increase the WSFC failover threshold

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, failover

Im trying to simulate the Failover in my SQL server 2017 alwayson by stopping and starting the SQL server service.

It worked 2 times, but after that, the failover is not happening, It showing an error like,

> Clustered role 'sqlag' has exceeded its failover threshold.  It has exhausted the configured number of failover attempts within the failover period of time allotted to it and will be left in a failed state.
> No additional attempts will be made to bring the role online or fail it over to another node in the cluster.  Please check the events associated with the failure.  After the issues causing the failure are resolved the role can be brought online manually or the cluster may attempt to bring it online again after the restart delay period.

I tried to change the Alwayson group resource restart timeout values like this. But still the failover is not happening, can someone help me where to increase this failover threshold?

[image]

And I tried even the max allowed values, but getting error like this.

> Cluster resource 'sqlag' of type 'SQL Server Availability Group' in clustered role 'sqlag' failed.

Based on the failure policies for the resource and role, the cluster service may try to bring the resource online on this node or move the group to another node of the cluster and then restart it.  Check the resource and group state using Failover Cluster Manager or the Get-ClusterResource Windows PowerShell cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Roles, click on AG and on the bottom you have resources - click on it.
Then open properties of Other resource - Your AG and go to Policies and play with those values.

[image]